# Msbuild tries to build msbuild.exe instead of my .csproj file

Tags: .net, msbuild, visual-studio-2022

I have a problem with the `msbuild` installation on a virtual machine.

I am using:

- Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition
- .Net Framework v4.8.1
- msbuild version `MSBuild version 17.5.0+6f08c67f3 for .NET Framework - 17.5.0.10706`
- Windows 10

If I create a a fresh "Hello World" C# project (.Net Framework v4.8.1) then it won't build.

Visual Studio shows an error at the top:
[image]

The error is:

```
=====================
16-03-2023 18:59:11
Recoverable
Microsoft.Build.Framework.InternalErrorException: MSB0001: Internal MSBuild Error: Cannot acquire required number of nodes.
=============
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeFailedToLaunchException: Den angivne fil blev ikke fundet
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeLauncher.StartInternal(String msbuildLocation, String commandLineArgs)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeLauncher.DisableMSBuildServer(Func`1 func)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<GetNodes>g__StartNewNode|2(Int32 nodeId)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<GetNodes>b__0(Int32 nodeId)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeFailedToLaunchException: Den angivne fil blev ikke fundet
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeLauncher.StartInternal(String msbuildLocation, String commandLineArgs)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeLauncher.DisableMSBuildServer(Func`1 func)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<GetNodes>g__StartNewNode|2(Int32 nodeId)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<GetNodes>b__0(Int32 nodeId)<---


 ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeFailedToLaunchException: Den angivne fil blev ikke fundet
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeLauncher.StartInternal(String msbuildLocation, String commandLineArgs)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeLauncher.DisableMSBuildServer(Func`1 func)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<GetNodes>g__StartNewNode|2(Int32 nodeId)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<GetNodes>b__0(Int32 nodeId)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ErrorUtilities.ThrowInternalError(String message, Exception innerException, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.GetNodes(String msbuildLocation, String commandLineArgs, Int32 nextNodeId, INodePacketFactory factory, Handshake hostHandshake, NodeContextCreatedDelegate createNode, NodeContextTerminateDelegate terminateNode, Int32 numberOfNodesToCreate)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProc.CreateNodes(Int32 nextNodeId, INodePacketFactory factory, Func`2 configurationFactory, Int32 numberOfNodesToCreate)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeManager.AttemptCreateNode(INodeProvider nodeProvider, NodeConfiguration nodeConfiguration, Int32 numberOfNodesToCreate)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeManager.CreateNodes(NodeConfiguration configuration, NodeAffinity nodeAffinity, Int32 numberOfNodesToCreate)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.PerformSchedulingActions(IEnumerable`1 responses)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.<>c__DisplayClass95_0.<IssueBuildRequestForBuildSubmission>g__IssueBuildSubmissionToSchedulerImpl|1(BuildSubmission submission, Boolean allowMainThreadBuild)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.<>c__DisplayClass95_0.<IssueBuildRequestForBuildSubmission>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.ProcessWorkQueue(Action action)
```

If I try to run `msbuild` from the `Developer powershell` in Visual studio the following error appears:

```
> msbuild .\ConsoleApp2.csproj
MSBuild version 17.5.0+6f08c67f3 for .NET Framework
MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
    Full command line: '"C:\PROGRA~1\MIB055~1\2022\COMMUN~1\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe" .\ConsoleApp2.csproj'
  Switches appended by response files:
'' came from 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.rsp'
Switch: .\ConsoleApp2.csproj

For switch syntax, type "MSBuild -help"
```

Which seems rather weird, it looks like it tries to run the command.
Where it have inserted itself as an argument to itself.

```
"C:\PROGRA~1\MIB055~1\2022\COMMUN~1\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe" .\ConsoleApp2.csproj
```

If I tried to just run `msbuild`, it looks like `msbuild` is trying to build `msbuild.exe` and obvious fails.

```
> msbuild
MSBuild version 17.5.0+6f08c67f3 for .NET Framework
Build started 16-03-2023 19:29:57.
Included response file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.rsp

Project "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe" on node 1 (default targets).
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe(1,1): error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Dataene på rodniveau er ugyldige. linje 1, position 1.
Done Building Project "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe" (default targets) -- FAILED.


Build FAILED.

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe" (default target) (1) ->
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe(1,1): error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Dataene på rodniveau er ugyldige. linje 1, position 1.

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.04
```

I do not know where this extra `msbuild` comes from.

I have tried:

- Re-install Visual Studio 2022
- Check environment variables - all looks normal
- Checked the file `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.rsp` - it only contain the default comments

How can `msbuild` be fixed so it can build projects again?

Comment: Just want to confirm. whether all of the projects you created have this issue? To avoid solution settings cause this issue, please go to the root directory of the solution, delete the .vs folder and obj/bin folder, then open the solution and try again.

Comment: Also try to clean the caches under C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_xxx\ComponentModelCache

Comment: I can confirm, it is all projects I try and build on that specific PC. I have tried to delete the .vs folder, and tried to create an empty new "hello world" solution with only a hello world project in it.

Comment: I have tried to clean the Cache and I get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be specific rules in place for that particular filename in that particular location.

You should be able to fix this issue by opening the Registry Editor and changing the value for MSBuild.exe.

Go to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options` find the entry for MSBuild.exe and delete it.

Source: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-cannot-find-make-sure-you-typed-the-name/6c60a27d-115f-474b-aaf7-2ac3d8367f26?page=1

Answer (score 2):

The solution **DictationScratchPad** found worked!

I do not know where the keys came from, but I had the following keys in registry. (Exported from registry before i deleted them)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\MSBuild.exe]
"HTag"=dword:00000000
"UseFilter"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\MSBuild.exe\0]
"HTag"=dword:00000000
"Debugger"="ntsd -c q"
"FilterFullPath"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\MSBuild\\Current\\Bin\\amd64\\MSBuild.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\MSBuild.exe\1]
"HTag"=dword:00000000
"Debugger"="ntsd -c q"
"FilterFullPath"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\MSBuild\\Current\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe"
```

Deleting them solved the problem, `msbuild` now works normally.

Comment: Get rid of Avast asap, it is not suitable for a programmer's machine.

Comment: Avast is not installed on it, it has "Heimdal Thor Agent" installed as its anti-virus.