# MSB0001: Internal MSBuild Error: Cannot acquire required number of nodes

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild

After a time using Visual Studio for do simple codes, I could not compile and debug any projects with the following error.

> ===================== 30/05/2023 19:36:53 Recoverable Microsoft.Build.Framework.InternalErrorException: MSB0001: Internal
> MSBuild Error: Cannot acquire required number of nodes.
> ============= System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeFailedToLaunchException: I criteri di integrità del sistema sono stati violati.  File esplicito negato    at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeLauncher.StartInternal(String
> msbuildLocation, String commandLineArgs)    at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeLauncher.DisableMSBuildServer(Func`1 func) at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<GetNodes>g__StartNewNode|2(Int32 nodeId)    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<GetNodes>b__0(Int32 nodeId)    --- End of inner exception stack trace --- ---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeFailedToLaunchException: I criteri di integrità del sistema sono stati violati.  File esplicito negato    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeLauncher.StartInternal(String msbuildLocation, String commandLineArgs)    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeLauncher.DisableMSBuildServer(Func`1 func)
> at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.g__StartNewNode|2(Int32
> nodeId)    at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.b__0(Int32
> nodeId)<---
>
> ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeFailedToLaunchException: I criteri di
> integrità del sistema sono stati violati.  File esplicito negato    at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeLauncher.StartInternal(String
> msbuildLocation, String commandLineArgs)    at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeLauncher.DisableMSBuildServer(Func`1 func) at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<GetNodes>g__StartNewNode|2(Int32 nodeId)    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<GetNodes>b__0(Int32 nodeId)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ErrorUtilities.ThrowInternalError(String message, Exception innerException, Object[] args)    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.GetNodes(String msbuildLocation, String commandLineArgs, Int32 nextNodeId, INodePacketFactory factory, Handshake hostHandshake, NodeContextCreatedDelegate createNode, NodeContextTerminateDelegate terminateNode, Int32 numberOfNodesToCreate)    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProc.CreateNodes(Int32 nextNodeId, INodePacketFactory factory, Func`2 configurationFactory,
> Int32 numberOfNodesToCreate)    at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeManager.AttemptCreateNode(INodeProvider
> nodeProvider, NodeConfiguration nodeConfiguration, Int32
> numberOfNodesToCreate)    at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeManager.CreateNodes(NodeConfiguration
> configuration, NodeAffinity nodeAffinity, Int32 numberOfNodesToCreate)
> at
> Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.PerformSchedulingActions(IEnumerable`1 responses)    at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.<>c__DisplayClass96_0.<IssueBuildRequestForBuildSubmission>g__IssueBuildSubmissionToSchedulerImpl|1(BuildSubmission submission, Boolean allowMainThreadBuild)    at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.<>c__DisplayClass96_0.<IssueBuildRequestForBuildSubmission>b__0() at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.ProcessWorkQueue(Action action) =================== 30/05/2023 19:39:21 Recoverable Microsoft.Build.Framework.InternalErrorException: MSB0001: Internal MSBuild Error: Cannot acquire required number of nodes. ============= System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeFailedToLaunchException: I criteri di integrità del sistema sono stati violati.  File esplicito negato    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeLauncher.StartInternal(String msbuildLocation, String commandLineArgs)    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeLauncher.DisableMSBuildServer(Func`1 func)
> at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.g__StartNewNode|2(Int32
> nodeId)    at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.b__0(Int32
> nodeId)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> ---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeFailedToLaunchException: I criteri di
> integrità del sistema sono stati violati.  File esplicito negato    at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeLauncher.StartInternal(String
> msbuildLocation, String commandLineArgs)    at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeLauncher.DisableMSBuildServer(Func`1 func)
> at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.g__StartNewNode|2(Int32
> nodeId)    at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.b__0(Int32
> nodeId)<---
>
> ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeFailedToLaunchException: I criteri di
> integrità del sistema sono stati violati.  File esplicito negato    at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeLauncher.StartInternal(String
> msbuildLocation, String commandLineArgs)    at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeLauncher.DisableMSBuildServer(Func`1 func) at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<GetNodes>g__StartNewNode|2(Int32 nodeId)    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<GetNodes>b__0(Int32 nodeId)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ErrorUtilities.ThrowInternalError(String message, Exception innerException, Object[] args)    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.GetNodes(String msbuildLocation, String commandLineArgs, Int32 nextNodeId, INodePacketFactory factory, Handshake hostHandshake, NodeContextCreatedDelegate createNode, NodeContextTerminateDelegate terminateNode, Int32 numberOfNodesToCreate)    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProc.CreateNodes(Int32 nextNodeId, INodePacketFactory factory, Func`2 configurationFactory,
> Int32 numberOfNodesToCreate)    at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeManager.AttemptCreateNode(INodeProvider
> nodeProvider, NodeConfiguration nodeConfiguration, Int32
> numberOfNodesToCreate)    at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeManager.CreateNodes(NodeConfiguration
> configuration, NodeAffinity nodeAffinity, Int32 numberOfNodesToCreate)
> at
> Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.PerformSchedulingActions(IEnumerable`1
> responses)    at
> Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.<>c__DisplayClass96_0.g__IssueBuildSubmissionToSchedulerImpl|1(BuildSubmission
> submission, Boolean allowMainThreadBuild)    at
> Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.<>c__DisplayClass96_0.b__0()
> at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.ProcessWorkQueue(Action
> action)
> ===================

Comment: Please don't cite compiler messages, post them as pre-formated text / code.

Comment: What is the version of the VS Tools you are using? Try to repair the VS Tool via the VS installer tool. And by the way, check the similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75760487/msbuild-tries-to-build-msbuild-exe-instead-of-my-csproj-file

Comment: And what is the compiler you were using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT the compiler version is the \MSVC\14.35.32215\

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT i tried to do what tell here { https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75760487/msbuild-tries-to-build-msbuild-exe-instead-of-my-csproj-file } but on the Image File Execution Options i don't have any entry for MSBuild.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to post this as an answer for lack of comment space, albeit it might not be an actual answer.

If I translate the Italian in your exception message, I get:

```
The system integrity policy has been violated. Explicit file denied at
```

This message is caused by SAC (Smart App Control) denying something. Maybe the number of (existing) MSBuild processes (msbuild.exe) already running.

You could try to kill all existing (possibly remaining) by using something like `taskkill.exe /IM msbuild.exe /F` (preferrably, while you have no build running ;-)).

Other than that, there seem to be a number of reasons which could cause this error (if you google for "MSB00001 cannot acquire number of nodes" you will find some hints/links).

Comment: When i write in the prompt this 'taskkill.exe /IM msbuild.exe /F', it respond to me: ERROR: "msbuild.exe" process not found.

Comment: OK, that just means that no msbuild.exe processes are left running. So it is unlikely, that the issue is caused by some leftover processes from previous runs.